# How to measure Firebase Functions startup time?

Tags: firebase, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm just about to do some improvements in my Firebase Functions in order to try to speed up the startup time, but I'm not sure how to measure it, in order to see if my changes are getting it faster or slower.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace) to measure every request that your Functions make or receive; with Cloud Trace you can see a detailed view of how many milliseconds takes to complete certain requests.

You can also integrate with Cloud Logging to gather more details, like the agent that made the request to see for example, maybe the requests take more in Mozilla than Chrome.

[Here is a guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-function-logs-traces#0) that could help you set up and use Trace to compare response times.

Answer (score -1):

Send a timestamp from caller as a parameter to your function.
Then inside function take another timestamp and measure it with one you get from caller.

Comment: That's going to work only the first time. Then, the function is already "started". I should have to restart the production server on every try.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect answer. I understand from your question that you want to measure startup time of the "cold" and/or "warm" functions depending on source code, included libraries, allocated memory, region or some other parameter.